# How to configure user-wide proxy in non-gnome Linux?

Tags: xubuntu, proxy

I'm using Xubuntu linux and want to configure user-wide proxy (non system wide in /etc/environment). I have heard about `export http_proxy=` variable, but how to apply it to XFCE session? And will it work fro all apps? Are there any tools except gnome-settings, that can do it? Graphical or non doesn't matter